# order by descending date is not working?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

```
SELECT convert(VARCHAR, WH.DATE, 103),
    PN.partyname,
    BT.birdname,
    dt.totalweight,
    dt.rateperkg,
    dt.dcno,
    mr.branch
FROM K_RT_Dailyentryretail DT
INNER JOIN K_RT_PartyName PN
    ON pn.sno = dt.partyname
INNER JOIN K_RT_WarehouseDetails WH
    ON dt.branchdate = wh.sno
INNER JOIN K_RT_BirdType BT
    ON dt.birdtype = bt.sno
INNER JOIN K_RT_MasterRetailStores MR
    ON MR.sno = WH.branch
WHERE MR.branch + ' - ' + convert(VARCHAR, WH.DATE, 103) = @date
ORDER BY convert(VARCHAR, WH.DATE, 103) DESC
```

here..order by date is not working.  How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show us some sample output?

Comment: you know you are ordering the converted date? and i just checked it gives for today 11/12/2013 so it means you could have 11/12/2013 followed by 01/10/2012 cause it's a string :)

Comment: Branch Date: Madhapur - 08/12/2013,Branch Date: Madhapur - 03/12/2013,Branch Date: Nizampet - 08/12/2013,Branch Date: Madhapur - 09/12/2013

Comment: output like above datewise desc order.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing:

```
order by convert(varchar,WH.date,103) desc
```

to:

```
order by WH.date desc
```

Answer (score 1):

when you are sorting on a date, converted to a varchar string using format "103", the date-string looks like this:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

So, the sort, will sort first by "dd", then "mm", then "yyyy".

You can DISPLAY the date in the format using 103, but when you do the order by, use this:

```
order by WH.date desc
```